# How to set authority to request token for the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am using `azure.identity.aio` python SDK to get access_token. For that I use ClientSecretCredential() class. This is current code that I have:

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_secret=client_secret)
access_token = credential.get_token("{host}/.default".format(host=host))
```

But I get `Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request` error when I set national cloud host such as `graph.microsoft.us`. I guess, one option is explicitly setting the authority:

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_secret=client_secret,authority=AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_GOVERNMENT)
```

But what if the login or api host is `graph.microsoft.de` or `graph.microsoft.cn`. Is there any way to dynamically set the authority based on the specified hostname?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically setting authority? Do you want to input hostname and set authority accordingly while getting token like this? https://i.imgur.com/GpNdtSv.png

Comment: @Sridevi Yes, you are correct. what does your get_authority_for_host(host) do?

Comment: You can define a function like that wraps authority based on host entered by user like this https://i.imgur.com/UNvISH2.png Check once and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below python code to set **authority** dynamically based on specified hostname, while requesting token for MS Graph:

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential, AzureAuthorityHosts

def get_authority_for_host(host):
    # Map hosts to the corresponding authority URLs
    host_authority_mapping = {
        "graph.microsoft.us": AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_GOVERNMENT,
        "graph.microsoft.de": AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_GERMANY,
        "graph.microsoft.cn": AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_CHINA,
        # Add more mappings as needed
    }
    return host_authority_mapping.get(host, AzureAuthorityHosts.AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD)

tenant_id = "tenant_id"
client_id = "app_id"
client_secret = "secret"

host = input("Enter hostname: ")
print()

authority = get_authority_for_host(host)

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id, 
    client_secret=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

access_token = credential.get_token("https://{host}/.default".format(host=host))
print(access_token.token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in **[jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)** website, I got claims with **`aud`** as below:

[image]